# Referencing a file static variable from an inline function

Tags: c++

Say you have a file example.h

```
class example
{
public:
    int doStuff();
};
```

and a file example.cpp

```
#include "example.h"
static const int data[] = {1, 2};

inline int doStuffImpl()
{
    return data[0] + data[1];
}

int example::doStuff()
{
    return doStuffImpl();
}
```

When I compile the equivalent on solaris using the native compiler, I get a linker error that it can't find the symbol 'data'. Is what I'm doing invalid?

Comment: I think you are mixing java syntax here?? Also can you please type the g++ version you are using in Solaris as well the other operating system where it worked? Also the command line options you specify?

Comment: Does the problem disappear when you remove the `inline` qualifier?

Comment: Although this is interesting, do you came over this in real code? Because in this trivial example, there's no use to extract `doStuffImpl()` into a separate function - you could as well do it all inside `example::doStuff()`.

Comment: Edits like your latest one make me think this isn't your real code and you're just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @Romaan I'm not even sure that with "native compiler" g++ is meant. Doesn't Sun (or Oracle if you want) have their own compiler anymore? I remember working on HP-UX where we were to use the system compiler and just installed the gnu compiler when we were too frustrated by the missing compiler diagnosis (aka warnings and errors).

Comment: yeah, it's not my real code, it (should be) equivalent for our purposes though. I'll admit I didn't try compiling it before I posted. The problem was not in the declaration of the static variable. The same code (again, not the code in the question, but equivalent code) compiles fine on windows (VS2008 & VS2010) and linux (gcc, I'm not sure which version atm)

Comment: @Axel , I work with Solaris machine at Oracle Labs and I pretty much use (GNU as you said) g++ to compile c++ source code. I think there should not be any difference regarding the code posted in the question to compile on any OS, provided the user uses the same compiler with compiler version being same.

Comment: Also, by native compiler I meant the one in Sun Studio, not gcc.

Comment: What happens if you remove the static from the declaration of data and put it into the unnamed namespace instead?

Comment: @Axel, same problem when we did that. We fixed it eventually by making the data & helper functions private static members of the class.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not, it should be

```
static const int data[] = {1, 2};
```

Comment: @Axel maybe in Java, in C++ no they are not.

Comment: Note, that `static` is superfluous here: `const` makes a file or namespace scope variable link with internal linkage, same as `static` does.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Just checked. Seems I was wrong. Should really be doing some C++ again sometime soon... :-/